# when Viewpager upglide ,TabLayout Stay on top

Tags: android

I want to produce a result，like  this:
[this is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfjum.jpg)

,when I upglide the ListView to top,the TabLayout will stop at top,I use google search the problem，but I can`t get a good answer，who can helper me?thanks very match

Comment: add your codes please

Comment: I just want to how to do

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup you TabLayout with ViewPager?

```
tab.setUpWithViewPager(pager)
```

Comment: Is not the problem，please look at the Look at the pictures，I mean,when listView upglide,tabLayout can hover on the top.

Comment: You mean , you want to hide the tabLayout?

Comment: I want to tabLayout Stop at the top

Comment: i think you meant this, https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout